# What is the point of seq in absurd function definition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Function definition looks like this:

```
absurd :: Void -> a
absurd a = a `seq` spin a where
  spin (Void b) = spin b
```

It makes any difference?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to actually construct a value of type Void. Therefore, any value you have that claims to be of type Void must be some sort of error. By seq'ing the value, the error is surfaced.

For the original issue requesting this feature, see: https://github.com/ekmett/void/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

That definition is real old, used only for backwards compatibility in the `void` package. The version in `base` is much simpler:

```
data Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd x = case x of
```

That empty `case` is a relatively new feature. The version in `void` is compatible with older GHC versions, and tries to thread a weird needle of getting good error messages (by forcing the value) and letting GHC know that evaluation will fail (for dead code removal). It's not the most reliable thing. But really, it's probably not worth worrying too much about now.

Comment: TIL `((undefined :: Void) == undefined) = True`.  Weird.

Comment: @luqui, I agree it's weird. Edward Kmett likes it that way.